# Navigate to grand-child route Angular 6

Tags: angular6

I am having issues navigating to a grand child route. The default route for the paths for the grand child works. When I am trying to navigate to the 'text' route, it doesn't recognize the route.

I have the following routes setup:

```
  { 
    path: '', 
    pathMatch: 'full',
    component: EmailListComponent,
    children:[
      {
        path: '',
        component: EmptyComponent
      }
    ]
  },
  { 
    path: 'editor', 
    pathMatch: 'full',
    component: EmailListComponent, 
    children: [
      { 
        path: '',
        component: MessageEditorComponent,
        children: [
          {
            path: 'text',
            component: TextActionBarComponent,
          },
          { 
            path: '',
            component: NoActionBarComponent,
          }    
        ]
      },
    ]
  }
```

I am trying to navigation this route using:

```
this.router.navigate(['/editor/text'], {});
```

I have also tried

```
this.router.navigate(['text'], {});
```

and

```
this.router.navigate(['/text'], {});
```